# Cordova AppRate Plugin

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I am finishing up the development of an app using Cordova. I have installed the AppRate plugin and it is working as it should. However, when running the app on an IPhone and opening up the rate page for the app, there is no back button. Android and Windows both have a way of getting directly back to the app, but in ios, there is no way without closing the browser and clicking on the app again. Can anyone help. I would like a back button or a button to close the browser

Comment: Does this plugin knows the user has already rated the app and would disable the popup in the future ? Or does it repeatedly bring up the popup even after the user rated the app ?